# Tachanun on a day when one is naming a baby girl

Tags: halacha, women, tachanun, baby-infant

This morning in Shul a fellow named his daughter, and Tachanun was said. To the best of my knowledge this is correct, as it is only mentioned not to say Tachanun when there is a Bris. Is there any source that says not to say Tachanun when a girl is being named?

Comment: "I believe what I am asking for doesn't exist. Does it exist?" is a funny form for a question here.

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=28334